# how to extend long-lived Facebook user access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

When I debug my Facebook user access token I see two expiration dates (*Expires* and *Data Access Expires*) as you can see here:
[image]

according to this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data/), token should expire 60 days after the last use but I'm seeing never and I don't know why! also when I exchange the user access token via this [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived), Data Access Expires does not change and I still get the same *Data Access token Expires*. My Facebook App is in development mode and I don't pass App Review yet. Also, I don't use FacebookSDK. do you know why I get never expires and why after exchanging the User Access token, *Data access Expires* doesn't extend?

Comment: _"why after exchanging the User Access token, Data access Expires doesn't extend?"_ - because data access isn't tied to the specific token?

Comment: @CBroe Oh man thank you very much. so is there any way to update it?  for example can I call some API periodically to extend this? and also do you know why never is set in expires?

Comment: It should automatically update, when the user performs API calls within your app. _"for example can I call some API periodically to extend this?"_ - why should you? This limitation was implemented for a reason, so why try and circumvent it? Asking a user who has not done anything within your app for three month, for access again, should be perfectly fine.

Comment: _"and also do you know why never is set in expires?"_ - probably because you asked for page management permissions as well. Page access tokens derived from long-lived user tokens are unlimited, and technically that is implemented by making the user token unlimited as well.

Comment: @CBroe thank you very much! really appreciate it man!